# Default access specifier in Java is accessible from outside the class

Tags: java

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String arg[]) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Using `javac HelloWorld.java` and `java HelloWorld`, the code compiles and runs well. Since default access specifier in Java is `package`, how is it possible? It must have protection from outsider...

Comment: class can not access outside package, but here is not that concept.
you have just run this class, so access specifier not comes into picture..

Comment: which outsider going to use it..? here no outsider going to use HelloWorld class.

Comment: Err, the classes that are accessing it successfully are in the same package?

Answer (score 1):

Access modifier restricts access during compile time. But it is allowed to load a class with any access modifier, use reflection to find the main method and run it. This is what java tool does when lanching from a class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 0):

Default Access modifier means you can only access that class in that package.

what you are doing here is, running and compiling the class.
This has nothing to do with modifiers and accessibility.

You will always Run & Compile classes like that.

What matters is that your class is accessible in the class or package that is being run.

You can not access a class with Default modifier in sub package or other package. A default class will only be accessible i the same package, otherwise you will get compile time error.

As far as your code is concerned you are doing nothing like that.

Suppose -

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String arg[]) { 
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
}
```

And

```
Class Hello extends HelloWorld{
// some code here
}
```

Now if you compile class Hello, then it will give you following error.

```
 class, interface, or enum expected
```